How to retain resized DataGrid column when changing DataTable in Highcharts?
Calling setCell() on a DataTable resets the column width if it had been resized.
How do I avoid the columns resetting their size?
I reproduced this using the demo code from https://www.highcharts.com/demo/dashboards/datagrid-sync:

Store in global: var theboard = Dashboards.board(...)
Resize any column
Call theboard.dataPool.connectors["synchro-data"].table.setCell("Vitamin A", 0, 0)
Observe that the column size resets its width



In the current version of Highcharts Dashboards Datagrid, this feature is not available. However, a new release is coming soon that will prevent the cell size from being reset. This update is expected to be published later this week.

FYI: The release was rescheduled till the next week.
